# Java Method Overriding - accessing methods in parent - is this possible?

Tags: java, methods, reference, overriding, naming

Let's say I create an instance of a class and override one of its methods at the same time - like this

```
MyClass fred = new MyClass() {
    @Override
    public void mymethod() {
        super.mymethod();
        //call something here
    }
};
```

Now let's imagine I want to call a local method which has the SAME name and SAME (lack of) parameters as my overridden method - e.g. I have

```
public void mymethod() {
    //my stuff in here
}
```

How can I call that from within the overridden method (on the line //call something here)???

Is that even possible?  Using

```
this.mymethod();
```

causes an endless loop (the overriden method is simply calling itself)

Is there a way of accessing this method (other than via a static reference perhaps?)

Sorry if this is a common question - it's a hard thing to search for and the one question I found had no replies and wasn't really that well-phrased so I'm trying myself!!

Comment: Could you link to the other relevant question? Perhaps we can answer that one, too...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it was on StackOverflow - browsing back through my History for here doesn't show it up so I suspect it was on a 'clone' site - if I do chance across it again, I'll link it here tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a complier handy so I'm not 100% sure here, but try this:

```
ParentClass.this.myMethod();
```

Comment: Not a trick, though, part of the definition of addressing enclosing instances. If the actual type of `this` is `T`, you can always use `T.this` as a qualifier when invoking instance methods.

Comment: @John Peat: No, [JLS §15.8.4 Qualified this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4) applies.

Comment: @trashgod now I really am learning something new - thanks again!!

Comment: Right answer but not well expressed, since the containing class may not be MyClass (it was not specified in the question) - you want ParentClass.this.mymethod() where ParentClass could be MyClass, but probably isn't.

Comment: I'm glad it worked...it's been so long since I used it when it popped into my head, well, let's just say rust came out of my ears.  @Mark, I didn't know about [ideone](http://ideone.com/) - thanks for introducing that to me.

Comment: @Charles: surely this breaks down when the parent class is the same type (I'm *really* not sure what the use-case there would be, but it would break down, no?)

Comment: @Charles, you're right, I shouldn't have used MyClass.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Mark Elliot: it should work fine because the class in question is anonymous, no?

Comment: @Charles: nope, it's problematic: http://ideone.com/pOacJ vs. http://ideone.com/uQuI0

Comment: @Mark Elliot: you did not put in the necessary 'this', change `MyClass.mymethod()` to `MyClass.this.mymethod()` and try again.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly, but functioning solution:

```
final MyOtherClass parent = this;

MyClass fred = new MyClass() {
    @Override
    public void mymethod() {
        super.mymethod();
        parent.mymethod();
    }
};
```

I'm struggling to see the scenario where you need to do this for naming purposes, but it's useful to know that `this` in the anonymous class will refer to the anonymous class, not the "parent"; so if you find the need to access the parent's method it's a useful technique.

FWIW, here's a [working example](http://ideone.com/0rYqx).

Comment: Ah - that's kinda obvious (I'm feeling a bit of a berk now)!

I realise that, ideally, I'd use different names - if for no other reason than to aid readability - but that could be useful - thanks!

Comment: @John: right, the exact use-case of this is unclear, but I can imagine a situation where you're stuck with APIs you cannot control.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I fully understood the question but my guess is that you want something like this:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public void mymethod() {
        ....
    }

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        MyClass fred = new MyClass() {
            @Override
            public void mymethod() {
                super.mymethod();
                //call something here
                ParentClass.this.mymethod();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note `ParentClass.this.mymethod()`

Comment: It sure is but @Paul slightly beat @Charles to the chase - thanks tho!

Comment: Actually it's not my answer, it is Alex Gitelman's, and he beat Paul to it but Paul amended his answer.  Haha the evolving Internet, it rewrites short term history!

Comment: @Charles I think actually Paul was first. My observation is that once you try to elaborate the answer you lose time to market and someone beats you :)

Comment: @Alex Gitelman: true, and I meant that you were the first to post the accurate answer, Paul posted his first but it was initially a bit confused.